# Fit Leaflet ImageOverlay in polygon so image doesn't overflow

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leaflet ImageOverlay https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#imageoverlay to put a PNG image on top of a polygon (white line). I've already assigned transparent pixels to the pixels where there is no image. However, as you can see in the image, the PNG image goes outside of the polygon exterior line around the borders. How can I make it fit the polygon?

I think I might use z-index here but can't wonder how

[image: Example]

Comment: I guess that https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas cound be adapted to work with imageoverlays, or you could tile your data and just use that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. May you please elaborate what do you mean with "tile your data"? I will check this plugin

Comment: I mean "turn your raster file into a tile pyramid so ti can be loaded as a `L.TileLayer`, so the leaflet-boundary-canvas plugin would work with it".

Comment: @IvanSanchez considering this image is small, it would fit in one tile file at all levels of zoom. How could I load it as a `L.TileLayer` without splitting it in multiple PNG files that correspond to z,x,y coordinates as normal tiles do?

Comment: You can't as of now. That's why I'm thinking how much trouble it is to tile such a (small) image versus how much trouble is it to adapt leaflet-boundary-canvas.